# How to get week number using query in sql server2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to get the week number using query , i found some queries but in those queries they passed the date parameter directly but as my requirement date is unknown i need to get the date from another table.
 Can any body help me to complete this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes. with a little search I found

SELECT DATEPART( WEEK , GETDATE())

You can even go one step further and subst GETDATE() with any DATETIME field or variable.